# communication is very important in any era of the world

Tags: idiomatic-language

```
communication is very important in any era of the world
```

Is the sentence above idiomatic? The key is **any era of the world**

Comment: It seems "of the world" is unneeded, and makes it sound less natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn’t really work. “Any era” means “any time,” but “of the world” makes it sound like you meant “any place.” Putting them together is kind of confusing.

You could either delete “of the world” or replace it with “in history,” which is more consistent with “any era” because you are talking about time.